# How do I use a shit nugget?

Tags: south-park-the-stick-of-truth

When you go to the toilet, there is a mini game where you can press out a shit nugget and use it to attack your enemies. In one of the first fights, I was unable to use it though.

So how exactly do you use the turd nugget during a fight?

Comment: You totally just asked this for that title. :P

Comment: @OhFiddleDiddle Totally not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While in combat You have to select it from your inventory just as you would any other consumable item. Then use it on opponent.